# How to list all Sequences in netezza database?

Tags: sql, database, netezza

Is there a query I can run to display all the existing sequences created in a netezza database?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure the system tables containing that information are well documented in the Netezza manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search turns up a copy of the System Admin Guide:

http://www.scribd.com/chiruthac/d/63476250-Netezza-System-Admin-Guide#outer_page_459

According to that, the statement should be:

```
select *
from  _v_sequence
```